# what is an event required to close a dropdown when the outer space of that is clicked in the javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-listener

I have the below code. How I can close the dropdown when clicking the outer space or items of that?

I tried by `addEventListener('click', myFunction)` over `document but it not works. Also, I search questions of the stack, but more are about solutions with jquery. How to fix it?

```css
.block {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" style="position: relative;display: inline-block;">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="dropdown()" style="padding: 16px;font-size: 16px;border: none;cursor: pointer;">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown" style="display: none;position: absolute;min-width: 160px;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);z-index: 1;">
    <a href="#" style="color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" style="color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;">No</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function dropdown() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.add("block");
  }
</script>
```

If I use the below code, so even the dropdown does not open.

```
document.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.remove("block");
}
```

Thanks for your attention:)

Answer (score 0):

With your appraoch, it will close everytime any thing on the `document` is clicked. You do not want that.

Listen for `onclick` on the document, but exclude the scenario when it is clicked inside your box:

```css
.block {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" style="position: relative;display: inline-block;">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="dropdown()" style="padding: 16px;font-size: 16px;border: none;cursor: pointer;">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown" style="display: none;position: absolute;min-width: 160px;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);z-index: 1;">
    <a href="#" style="color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" style="color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;">No</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function dropdown() {  document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.add("block");
  }
  
  document.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
function myFunction(){
 if (!document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0].contains(event.target)){ document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.remove("block");
 }
 }
 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, please explain more about `!document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0].contains(event.target)`. also about two lines of your Explanation.